# Evaluate numerically an extremely small number

Tags: numerics, evaluation

How to evaluate numerically $e^{-4 \cdotp 10^{35}}$  in the form $0,a_1a_2...\times 10^{-n}$

```
N[E^(-4*10^35)]  

General::unfl: Underflow occurred in computation. >>
Underflow[]
```

doesn't work

Comment: How many digits would you be satisfied with?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
n = 35;
{pow, logdec} = {#[[1]][[;; #[[2]]]], #[[1]][[#[[2]] + 1 ;;]]} &@
                            RealDigits[N[Log[10, E^(-4 10^n)], 200]];
```

So there are

```
FromDigits@pow

(* 173717792761300731060451567566642032 *)
```

zeroes,followed by

```
dec = N[1/10^(FromDigits[logdec] 10^-Length[logdec]), 50]

(* 0.12084848148616706326389685430970719629910021783715 *)
```

... or may be I'm off by one :)

---

Checking with smaller numbers:

```
n=4;
{pow, logdec} = {#[[1]][[;; #[[2]]]], #[[1]][[#[[2]] + 1 ;;]]} &@
                 RealDigits[N[Log[10, E^(-4 10^n)], 200]];
FromDigits@pow
(* 17371 *)
dec = N[1/10^(FromDigits[logdec] 10^-Length[logdec]), 50]
0.16623553671520518223181112083319039297273582477854

E^(-4 10^n) // N
(* 1.66235536715*10^-17372 *)
```

Comment: Somewhat simpler: `exp = -4*10^35;
tenExp = Floor[exp/Log[10]];
rem = exp - tenExp Log[10];
N[Exp[rem], 50]*Inactivate@Power[10, tenExp]` Also, `rem` can be written as `Mod[exp, Log[10]]` but I wanted to make sure (and make it obvious) that the integer and fractional part add up right.

Answer (score 1):

```
$MinMachineNumber
```

$\text{2.2250738585072014$\grave{ }$*${}^{\wedge}$-308}$

and as Karsten 7 points out:

```
Log[$MinNumber]
```

$-3.121657384082590881601471993929\times 10^{15}$

---

Use `Exp[x] == 10^(x/Log[10])`

and `Exp[a b] = Exp[a] + Exp[b]` to find:

$0.0183156\ 10^{-10^{35}}$

Comment: That's for machine-precision. [`$MinNumber`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MinNumber.html?q=%24MinNumber) is more relevant here.